# WSO2 API Manager Store error when searching for an application

Tags: ajax, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm using WSO2 API Manager 2.1.0. When I search for an application in the store, the following error occurs from time to time. Once this occurs, any other application cannot be searched and the API Manager needs to be restarted to function normally.

Any supportive step(s) to troubleshoot this issue is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Datatable Error]

PS: I have also added the backend logs herewith.

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-06-07 14:02:26,786] ERROR {org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager} -  org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from null (/store/site/blocks/application/application-list/ajax/application-list.jag#98) {org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager}
org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from null (/store/site/blocks/application/application-list/ajax/application-list.jag#98)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:571)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.exec(WebAppManager.java:588)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:508)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doGet(JaggeryServlet.java:24)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:747)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:485)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:377)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:337)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.cache.ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.doFilter(ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:120)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
        at org.wso2.carbon.event.receiver.core.internal.tenantmgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:48)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:958)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1756)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1715)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from null (/store/site/blocks/application/application-list/ajax/application-list.jag#98)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3687)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3665)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3693)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError2(ScriptRuntime.java:3712)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.undefReadError(ScriptRuntime.java:3725)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getObjectProp(ScriptRuntime.java:1483)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.application.application_list.ajax.c0._c_anonymous_1(/store/site/blocks/application/application-list/ajax/application-list.jag:98)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.application.application_list.ajax.c0.call(/store/site/blocks/application/application-list/ajax/application-list.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call0(OptRuntime.java:23)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.application.application_list.ajax.c0._c_script_0(/store/site/blocks/application/application-list/ajax/application-list.jag:4)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.application.application_list.ajax.c0.call(/store/site/blocks/application/application-list/ajax/application-list.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.application.application_list.ajax.c0.call(/store/site/blocks/application/application-list/ajax/application-list.jag)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.application.application_list.ajax.c0.exec(/store/site/blocks/application/application-list/ajax/application-list.jag)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:567)
        ... 45 more
```

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned Ajax error is a general error if the Application-specific entries are not found in the API Manager or if there are any issues in the network calls when trying to retrieve the Application information.

To investigate further,

- You can open the Developer console in the Browser and inspect the Network during the operation. Check whether the operation (network call) related to retrieval (`https://<hostname>:<port>/store/site/blocks/application/application-list/ajax/application-list.jag`) is having any issues, and please do check the LB and Proxy configurations if those have been configured in your environment.
- Verify whether the errors are populated to only a set of Applications or for all applications randomly. If this is only happening for a set of applications, there can be issues with the data stored in the DB. Either the respective Application has partial data entered, or the APIs that have been subscribed with the application is having partial data

Focus on the URL configurations and LB configurations, as it can be a more general cause for the issue.